# Listenting to vscode-git commit events

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to build an extension with vscode, and  I want some action to be done while the user commits the code in their repo. Is there a way to listen to vscode-git API commit events from my custom extension ? I am using the API from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/git but I dont see any event that I can use for commits.

Thoughts ?

Comment: git has something called "git hooks". Use this as a search then you should be able to find similar notification from vscode. Also note that git handling in vscode is done by plugin and there many to choose from. So most probably each plugin does this in its own way.

Comment: Thanks Marek. yeah for now I am doing with git hooks and thought to leverage using API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `onDidCommit` event was recently added to the built-in git extension in vscode, see

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/5be6890cf5f60bec243715b92f33e97a197e1413

and

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/856d46ed86cacc939504e0d9d77fb8dfc12f9efc/extensions/git/src/api/api1.ts#L69

```
readonly onDidCommit: Event<void> = mapEvent<OperationResult, void>(filterEvent(this.repository.onDidRunOperation, e => e.operation === Operation.Commit), () => null);
```