# Listen for Git push event in a VSCode extension code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create a VSCode extension that listens to Git push events from a repository and fetches the commit ID, which is sent to an API (REST) and performs several other operations. I have tried two approaches till now: A `FileSystemWatcher` which watches for changes in the repo .git folder, and the other one being subscribing to RepositoryState's `onDidChange` event. Unfortunately, both approaches aren't working. Can anyone help me with a better solution for this requirement?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869701/836330